# UiImagePicker Video Played in Reverse

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm attempting to create a silly little app for myself to learn the ins and outs of UIImagePicker and possibly AV Foundation (if needed). What I want to do is allow the user to record a video and play it in reverse (starting at the end and going to the beginning).

So far I'm looking into using UIImagePicker to record the video and then MPMoviePlayerController to playback the video. Can anyone offer feedback on this process? My concerns are that UIImagePicker isn't the correct class to use, or that reverse video playback will be very choppy by using the setCurrentPlaybackRate:-1.0